# Custom Rofi menu wont return selected value

Tags: bash, xrandr, i3

I am trying to make a Rofi menu within i3wm that I can call to adjust external monitors and such. I am able to call and run the script perfectly fine however When I select an option from the menu nothing is returned and the commands to adjust the screens are never called. Info on rofi can be found here (https://github.com/davatorium/rofi).

Is there a special way to call the commands? Am I not formatting the custom menu correctly?

This is the script I am calling: (https://pastebin.com/Uev1tiR5)

```
#!/bin/bash

seleted=$(echo "Laptop Only
HDMI Only
Display Port Only
Dual Monitor" | rofi -dmenu -p "Select Monitor Setup: ")

echo You Picked: " $selected"

if [ "$selected" == "Laptop Only" ]; then
    xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --primary --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output DP-1 --off --output HDMI-0 --off --output DP-1-2 --off --output DP-1-1 --off --output DP-0 --off
    exit
fi
if [ "$selected" == "HDMI Only" ]; then
    exit
fi
if [ "$selected" == "Display Port Only" ]; then
    exit
fi
if [ "$selected" == "Dual Monitor" ]; then
    xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --primary --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1920x0 --rotate normal --output DP-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 3840x0 --rotate normal --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output DP-1-2 --off --output DP-1-1 --off --output DP-0 --off
    exit
fi
```

What should happen is the selected value is used in the if statements and the correct command is called. Two of the menu options I havent generated an xrandr command for yet so they just say exit.

Comment: *`seleted` appears unused*. Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Am I referencing it wrong in the if statements and in the echo right after I define it then?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the past hour or two of googleing and finally this post was all because of a typo when i defined selected. Thanks for the help, sorry to waste time on such a stupid mistake.